# How to convert codec of video recorded by inbuilt Android camera?

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-mediacodec

I record video using the inbuilt camera of android,but when I send to server via Retrofit2,the video cannot seen in browser.So after long time of searching,I know that the video that I record by android,the codec is `MP42` so I need to convert it to `H.264` codec in order to make it playable in browser.

**Here is how I capture the video**

```
 private void recordVideo() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,fileUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,15);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == RECORD_VIDEO_PERMISSION && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri =data.getData(); //so the video file I get it here 
            Log.d("videoData",data.getData().toString());
            videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
            videoView.start();
        }
    }
```

I get the uri of the video in `onActivityResult`,the video is in `MP42` codec,how can I convert it to `H.264`?

I tried to use [MediaCodec Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html),but I didnt know where to input my `Uri` (mp42) to get the output in H.264 codec video(which I want to play in browser).

Somebody please give me some guidance..

Comment: mp42 is a container (it is also a MScodec but Doubt this is the case here) - can you share a link to an example video and we may be able to help better

Comment: this video is MP42 which I direct upload it to server..it just appear like this

Comment: Use `MediaRecorder` API to capture video. During the setup code you can choose H.264 as codec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) **Fixing current video file :**

Your video is of format **H.263** (or Mpeg-2) using `Simple` profile. Correctly as you said, this means you must convert. You must do this **re-encode** into H.264 task using some free video tool.

For example : Using [**Handbrake**](https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php) you can do...

- Choose to Open your *"not playing"* MP4 file. Should be detected as MP4, now tick (or enable) the option `web optimized`.
- In `Video` settings tab, choose Encoder`Profile` as **Main** and Encoder `level` as **3**.
- In `Destination` put your preferred output folder and filename.
   (just browse to some folder then type your new filename to create here).
- Click green button `Start Encode` and test new MP4 output file in browser.

(2) **Fixing Android code for future recordings :**

You have to set the codec to H.264 in your `MediaRecorder` object settings like :

```
myMediaRec = new MediaRecorder(); //create MediaRecorder object
myMediaRec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264); //set video codec
```

So basically your code should look like : (untested code, just use for study or guidance)...

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if(requestCode == RECORD_VIDEO_PERMISSION && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        //# Create a new instance of MediaRecorder
        myMediaRec = new MediaRecorder(); //create MediaRecorder object
        mMediaRec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        myMediaRec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

        //# Video settings
        myMediaRec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264); //contained inside MP4
        myMediaRec.setVideoSize(640, 480); //width 640, height 480
        myMediaRec.setVideoFrameRate(30);  //30 FPS
        myMediaRec.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000); //adjust this for picture quality

        //# Audio settings
        myMediaRec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC); //must always be AAC
        myMediaRec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.getAudioSourceMax());
        myMediaRec.setAudioEncodingBitRate(16);
        myMediaRec.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70349561/use-mediarecorder-api-instead-of-intent-for-camera-recording-in-android